# Facebook Login : Attempt to insert non-property value '<null>' of class 'NSNull'

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am getting a message like below in the log when I am logging in via facebook

```
*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<null>' of class 'NSNull'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

What is its meaning?
Why this message is coming?

In facebook.m class I am setting like

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```

Comment: Please post your code. The error just means the setObject on the NSUserDefaults is null, it cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NSUserDefaults serializes its data to a property list (/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/[BUNDLE_ID].plist), all set properties should be property list object, i. e. NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSNumber, NSData or NSDate. If you want to remove a value of a key, use the `- removeObjectForKey:` message on NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Thank You.. Now that message is not getting..

Answer (score 5):

`[NSNull null]` can't be used with NSUserDefaults.

You could use [`removeObjectForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/removeObjectForKey:)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```

or if you insist on setting something you could set an empty string `@""`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```